# PostgreSQL performance tuning with table partitions

Tags: postgresql

I am solving an performance issue on PostgreSQL 9.6 dbo based system. Intro:

12yo system, similar to banking system, with most queried primary table called `transactions`.

```
CREATE TABLE jrn.transactions (
     ID BIGSERIAL,
     type_id VARCHAR(200),
     account_id INT NOT NULL,
     date_issued DATE,
     date_accounted DATE,
     amount NUMERIC,
     ..
)
```

In the table `transactions` we store all transactions within a bank account. Field `type_id` determines the type of a transaction. Servers also as C# EntityFramework Discriminator column. Values are like:

`card_payment`, `cash_withdrawl`, `cash_in`, ...

14 types of transaction are known.

In generally, there are 4 types of queries (no. 3 and .4 are by far most frequent):

1. select single transaction like: `SELECT * FROM jrn.transactions WHERE id = 3748734`
2. select single transaction with JOIN to other transaction like: `SELECT * FROM jrn.transactions AS m INNER JOIN  jrn.transactions AS r ON m.refund_id = r.id WHERE m.id = 3748734`
3. select 0-100, 100-200, .. transactions of given type like: `SELECT * FROM jrn.transactions WHERE account_id = 43784 AND type_id = 'card_payment' LIMIT 100`
4. several aggregate queries, like: `SELECT SUM(amount), MIN(date_issued), MAX(date_issued) FROM jrn.transactions WHERE account_id = 3748734 AND date_issued >= '2017-01-01'`

In last few month we had unexpected row count growth, now 120M.

We are thinking of table partitioning, following to PostgreSQL doc: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/ddl-partitioning.html

Options:

1. partition table by `type_id` into 14 partitions
2. add column `year` and partition table by `year` (or `year_month`) into 12 (or 144) partitions.

I am now restoring data into out test environment, I am going to test both options.

What do you consider the most appropriate partitioning rule for such situation? Any other options?

Thanks for any feedback / advice etc.

Comment: If queries 3 and 4 are the most frequent one's, we should try to optimize partitioning on them. Their `WHERE` conditions include three columns `account_id`, `type_id` and `date_issued`. The selectivity of `account_id` is very high, so it most likely should go better to an index. `date_issued` is used with non-equal operators, thus partitioning would not help much. `type_id` has no selectivity, so could be ok, but is not used in query 4. ==> there is no obvious solution (at least to me).

Comment: Note that you are referring to the docs of Postgresql 10, whilst your server is on 9.6.

Comment: On option 2: As query 4 does not contain `year`(or `year_mongth`), this does not help much either. Anyway, query 3 is not limited w.r.t. `date_issued`, so this would also not be an optimal solution.

Comment: I am currently thinking into the direction of a materialized view (e.g. for handling the aggregating query no. 4). @Luke1988: What is the update/insert frequency to `jrn.transactions` and how important is accuracy of `sum(amount)` in query 4?

Comment: Can you please shed some lights on what indices are available on your table so far?

Comment: Thanks for feedback. As far as I understood docu, year partition will allow query within date range of such year to be executed within smaller partition rather than whole table. However, this is just one case. No 3 is still uncovered by this partitio

Comment: Inserts are most frequent, almost no update and after batch of inserts (without a transaction) goes an aggregation select

Comment: What is the cardinality of `type_id` ? Why is it`varchar(200)` ?

Comment: Sorry, I wrote that query just from memory, like a pseudo code. Max length is 49 so column is set to varchar(50).

Comment: And IMHO it takes **two** accounts to make a transaction.

Comment: Indeen. First is yours, the accound_id and second is the other which has no relation entity joined with id, but only plain bank account number stored as VARCHAR. This and a lot of other fields are not included in piece of code. Do you consider them important to mention even if they are not included in any where/join statement?

Comment: Yes, because they are the most important foreign keys. Combined with one of the date fields, they  *almost* construct the natural key for the table.

Answer (score 2):

Partitioning won't be very helpful with these queries, since they won't perform a sequential scan, unless you forgot an index.

The only good reason I see for partitioning would be if you want to delete old rows efficiently; then partitioning by date would be best.

Based on your queries, you should have these indexes (apart from the primary key index):

```
CREATE INDEX ON jrn.transactions (account_id, date_issued);
CREATE INDEX ON jrn.transactions (refund_id);
```

The following index *might* be a good idea if you can sacrifice some insert performance to make the third query as fast as possible (you might want to test):

```
CREATE INDEX ON jrn.transactions (account_id, type_id);
```

Comment: Thank you! As far as I understand, partitioning wont be helpful due to account_id? If there is no account_id column (just theory now), then, partition by type_id would make a sence? I could possibly redirect query no 3. to this partiotion directly - `SELECT * FROM jrn.transactions_cash_withdrawl LIMIT 100`

Comment: Yes, if you partition by `type_id`, it would only scan that one partition. But if you have the appropriate index and use an index scan, that won't be much cheaper than on the big table. Partitioning only helps with plans that use a sequential scan and with mass deletion.

Answer (score 0):

What you have here is almost a perfect case for column-based storage as you may get it using a [SAP HANA Database](https://help.sap.com/viewer/6b94445c94ae495c83a19646e7c3fd56/2.0.00/en-US/bd2e9b88bb571014b5b7a628fca2a132.html). However, as you explicitly have asked for a Postgres answer and I doubt that a HANA database will be within the budget limit, we will have to stick with Postgres.

Your two queries no. 3 and 4 go quite into different directions, so there won't be "the single answer" to your problem - you will always have to balance somehow between these two use cases. Yet, I would try to use two different techniques to approach each of them individually.

From my perspective, the biggest problem is the query no. 4, which creates quite a high load on your postgres server just because it is summing up values. Moreover, you are just summing up values over and over again, which most likely won't change often (or even at all), as you have said that `UPDATE`s nearly do not happen at all. I furthermore assume two more things:

- `transactions` is `INSERT`-only, i.e. `DELETE` statements almost never happen (besides perhaps in cases of some exceptional administrative intervention).
- The values of column `date_issued` when `INSERT`ing typically are somewhere "close to today" - so you usually won't `INSERT` stuff way in the past.

Out of this, to prevent aggregating values over and over again unnecessarily, I would introduce yet another table: let's call it `transactions_aggr`, which is built up like this:

```
create table transactions_aggr (
   account_id INT NOT NULL,
   date_issued DATE,
   sumamount NUMERIC,
   primary key (account_id, date_issued)
)
```

which will give you a table of per-day preaggregated values. 
To determine which values are already preaggregated, I would add another boolean-typed column to `transactions`, which indicates to me, which of the rows are contained in `transactions_aggr` and which are not (yet). The query no. 4 then would have to be changed in such a way that it reads only non-preaggregated rows from `transactions`, whilst the rest could come from `transactions_aggr`. To facilitate that you could define a view like this:

```
select account_id, date_issued, sum(amount) as sumamount from
    (
    select account_id, date_issued, sumamount as amount from transactions_aggr as aggr
    union all
    select account_id, date_issued, sum(amount) as amount from transactions as t where t.aggregated = false
    )
group by account_id, date_issued
```

Needless to say that putting an index on `transactions.aggregated` (perhaps in conjunction with the `account_id`) could greatly help to improve the performance here.

Updating `transactions_aggr` can be done using multiple approaches:

1. You could use this as a one-time activity and only pre-aggregate the current set of ~120m rows once. This would at least reduce the load on your machine doing aggregations significantly. However, over time you will run into the same problem again. Then you may just re-execute the entire procedure, simply dropping `transactions_aggr` as a whole and re-create it from scratch (all the original data still is there in `transactions`).
2. You have a nice period somewhere during the week/month/in the night, where you have little or no queries are coming in. Then you can open a transaction, read all `transactions WHERE aggregated = false` and add them with `UPDATE`s to `transactions_aggr`. Keep in mind to then toggle `aggregated` to `true` (should be done in the same transaction). The tricky part of this, however, is that you must pay attention to what reading queries will "see" of this transaction: Depending on your requirements of accuracy during that timeframe of this "update job", you may have to consider switching the transaction isolation level to "READ_COMMITED" to prevent ghost reads.

On the matter of your query no. 3 you then could try to really go for the approach of partitioning based on `type_id`. However, I perceive your query as a little strange, as you are performing a `LIMIT`/`OFFSET` without ordering (e.g. there is no `ORDER BY` statement in place) having specified (NB: You are not saying that you would be using database cursors). This may lead to the effect that the implicit order, which is currently used, is changed, if you enable partitioning on the table. So be careful on side-effects which this may cause on your program. 
And one more thing: Before really doing the partition split, I would first check on the data distribution concerning `type_id` by issuing

```
select type_id, count(*) from transactions group by type_id
```

Not that it turns out that, for example, 90% of your data is with `card_payment` - so that you will have a heavily uneven distribution amongst your partitions and the biggest performance hogging queries are those which would still go into this single "large partition".

Hope this helps a little - and good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the effort! I ran that query. Data distribution is almost equal, ca. from 5 to 10% per type. One type is used very little, and two types are used more frequently, but not more than 20%. Bad think about transaction_aggregations is that the query is generated by the application layer and for now, any modification of the application is problematic and not in our hands. About query order: we use implicit order because we list transactions as they comes into system, so natural primary key order works fine.